# Extract resources from PE file via script/command-line

Tags: windows, scripting, executable

I want to write a script (or something similar. don't care which language) which extracts the resources from a PE file (.rsrc section). I'm using Python's pefile and peutils for various PE tasks, but couldn't find anything which actually extracts the resources.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks,
Moshe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does [PEDUMP](http://download.microsoft.com/download/msdnmagazine/code/Feb02/WXP/EN-US/PE.exe) work? See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301808.aspx) for the description on how to use it. From a quick scan [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ms809762.aspx) seems to show how to decode the resources section. Finally [this](http://www.devsource.com/c/a/Architecture/Retrieve-Resources-PE-II/) shows some c++ code to extract resources.

Comment: I recall looking at this article before. It seems the PEDUMP tool isn't available for download anymore.

Comment: or this on http://www.simtel.net/free-download/Programming-Utilities/pedumpzip/28111.html