# Extract/parse resources from Portable Executable (PE) file

Tags: command-line, compression, windows-installer, microsoft-edge, portable-executable

I want to install Edge in Windows programmatically using the official
[MSI Edge installer](https://msedge.sf.dl.delivery.mp.microsoft.com/filestreamingservice/files/0a8155d6-0937-4937-8712-1930f09598eb/MicrosoftEdgeEnterpriseX64.msi) (151 MB) but avoid the use of administrator permissions, and place the extracted files in a custom folder (not `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge`). I found a command which works, but unfortunately, it requires administrator permissions, namely:

```
msiexec /i MicrosoftEdgeEnterpriseX64.msi /qn
```

Therefore, I tried to extract the data encoded inside the MSI. After some manipulation of this MSI, I extracted a file called [MicrosoftEdge_X64_116.0.1938.76.exe](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1w2MxLRJt8KjJ9NlR0NfuTjf6wlHvxSQm/view?usp=drive_link) (145.7 MB), which seems to be a Portable Executable (PE) file (see [reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable)). But its format seems strange to me since most content is encoded in the `.rsrc` section.

[image]

As far as I believe, the `.rsrc` section in a PE file contains resources indexed by a multiple-level binary-sorted tree structure (see [source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/pe-format#the-rsrc-section)). But this PE file does not follow that, and that file seems like a binary file I cannot understand nor uncompress. So here is my question.

Does anybody know how to uncompress the content of the `.rsrc` section of that PE file?

Note: I checked related questions here (e.g., using [PEDUMP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218536/extract-resources-from-pe-file-via-script-command-line)) without success.

Comment: Looks like yet another installer bundled inside, and the resource section header doesn't make much sense (looks more like a big blob containing an archive of many files). You'll likely have to grab some disassembler and start digging...